# Android SDK and AVD Manager, Stalls and/or never finishes

Tags: android, android-emulator

Recorded for posterity.

I saw only a few posts around the net and all suggest to use HTTP instead of HTTPS and there were several ways to do this.  None of them discussed Windows only Linux.  Well this did not work for me and I could not find any way to get the files downloaded to my Windows Vista 64 machine.

So after much work I manually downloaded them and got them to work.   I did this by putting it on a machine that did work and reading the repository.xml file and downloading them.

https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google-apis-4_r02.zip

Unzipped it and moved the top directory into

android-sdk-windows/add-ons

and

https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android-1.6_r02-windows.zip

I then extracted them and renamed the top directory android-1.6 (it is at least one level below the unzipped directory) and moved it to

the platforms directory

Then rebooted my machine and it seems to work.

Hope this helps someone.

Julian

Comment: Julian, as much as I admire you sharing useful information to the community, the website is Q&A only.

Comment: Julian, if possible, can you post this to the **android-developers** Google Group? Thanks for documenting this!

Comment: @Anthony, Bodger: This was indeed partly helpful for me to analyze the issues I was facing. According to http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/ it is perfectly valid to post your own findings but you need to separate them into a question and an answer.

Comment: As an amendment - I did not find any repository.xml file in the android-sdk Directory. However by help of Wireshark I found the endpoint from where the SDK Manager was trying to download. The file names seem to follow a certain pattern, e.g. the file for the Android Platform for API 18 and Revision 2 is http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android-18_r02.zip. Opening the address in a browser window revealed that the McAfee WebWasher was blocking the ZIP due to a contained BIN file.

Answer (score 2):

you need to disable auto tuning on your network adapter. i was going crazy trying to figure this out.

run this in an administrator command prompt (right click command prompt from the start menu, run as administrator)

netsh interface tcp set global autotuning=disabled

restart avd manager

Comment: Updated to Android Studio 1.2 and this problem suddenly surfaced. Performing this BEFORE EACH PACKAGE ATTEMPT has fixed it - even for things like system images which are very large. If it's not done every time though my downloads stall.

Answer (score 2):

On Mac OS X, the corresponding command for turning off auto tuning is:

```
sudo sysctl -w net.inet.tcp.rfc1323=0
```

This fixed the issue for me.

Source: [Handling TCP Window Scaling](http://www.ecr6.ohio-state.edu/window-scaling.html)

Comment: Me too - but not permanently!  I have to re-issue the command whenever I try to update Android SDK/ADT after rebooting.